# How to align below Texts

Tags: html

**From This :**

```
GCPL- FY 2015-2016
GPL-FY 2015-2016
GIL-FY 2013-2014
```

To This:

```
GCPL - FY 2015-2016
GPL  - FY 2015-2016
GIL  - FY 2013-2014
```

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this?

Assumptions:

- Only word to pad is the first
- Dash after the first word has one leading and one trailing space

```js
const pad = (str, sp) => str.padStart(sp)
const strings = document.getElementById("before").textContent;

let longest = 0;
document.getElementById("after").textContent = strings.split("\n").map(
  str => {
    let parts = str.match(/(\w+)-(?:\s+)?(\w{2})+\s?(\d+-\d+)/);
    parts.shift(); // drop the complete result
    longest = Math.max(longest, parts[0].length)
    return parts;
  }).map(item => `${item[0].padEnd(longest)} - ${item.slice(1).join(" ")}`).join("\n")
```

```css
pre {
  display: block;
  unicode-bidi: embed;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<pre id="before">GCPL- FY 2015-2016
GPL-FY 2015-2016
GIL-FY 2013-2014</pre>
<pre id="after"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more information on how you're trying to achieve the result, what technology are you using.

For example if you're using a programming language like `JavaScript` to do so, you can try below snippet.

```js
var formatted = 
`GCPL- FY 2015-2016
GPL-FY 2015-2016
GIL-FY 2013-2014`
 .split("\n")
 .map((v) => v.split(/[\s-]*FY[\s-]*/).map(w => w.padEnd(5)).join(" - FY "))
 .join("\n");
  
  console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

An HTML solution:

```css
p.aligned-row span {
  display: inline-block;
}

p.aligned-row :first-child {
  width: 5ch;
}

p.aligned-row :nth-child(2) {
  width: 4ch;
}

p.aligned-row :nth-child(3) {
  width: 9ch;
}
```

```html
<p class="aligned-row"> <span>GCPL</span> <span>- FY</span> <span>2015-2016</span> </p>
<p class="aligned-row"> <span>GPL</span> <span>- FY</span> <span>2015-2016</span> </p>
<p class="aligned-row"> <span>GIL</span> <span>- FY</span> <span>2013-2014</span> </p>
```

Comment: interesting approach, it's great if OP is just looking for formatted presentation, but it might now work otherwise as really make changes in the text itself. If someone were to copy and paste this on notepad, it will again start to look jagged. For that use other 2 answers are better approach.

But, obviously none of this matters as the question is very unclear.